# Error when trying to send POST request

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I have an API on our webserver which provides data for our apps.  POST and GET requests work fine with Postman or using other tests.  GET requests appear to work fine in the app but POST requests come back with an error (tested with iPhone 6 simulator using iOS 10.2 on Xcode 8.2.1).

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "(null)" 
UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.mysite.com/api/Device/Login, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x6000002487f0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1012 "(null)" 
UserInfo={_kCFURLErrorAuthFailedResponseKey=<CFURLResponse 0x6000000fde00 [0x108d59df0]>
{url = https://api.mysite.com/api/Device/Login}}}, 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.mysite.com/api/Device/Login}

domain: @"NSURLErrorDomain" - code: 18446744073709550604
```

Here is the bulk of the function that creates the POST request:

```
-(NSString*)login:(NSString*)username password:(NSString*)password
{

NSString *deviceID = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
NSString *deviceModel = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
NSString *deviceOS = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
NSString *deviceOSName = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName];
NSString *pushEnabled = @"False";

NSArray *userDictObjects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:username, password, nil];
NSArray *userDictKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Username", @"Password", nil];
NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:userDictObjects forKeys:userDictKeys];

NSArray *deviceDictObjects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              deviceID,
                              deviceOSName,
                              deviceOS,
                              @"Apple",
                              deviceModel,
                              pushEnabled,
                              @"pushID", nil];
NSArray *deviceDictKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           @"DeviceID",
                           @"OS",
                           @"OSVersion",
                           @"Manufacturer",
                           @"Model",
                           @"PushEnabled",
                           @"PushID", nil];

NSDictionary *deviceDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:deviceDictObjects forKeys:deviceDictKeys];

NSArray *sectionsArrayObjects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:userDict, deviceDict, nil];
NSArray *sectionsArrayKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"User", @"Device", nil];

NSDictionary *sectionsDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:sectionsArrayObjects forKeys:sectionsArrayKeys];

NSLog(@"Json >  %@", sectionsDict);

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:sectionsDict options:0 error:nil];

NSString *conURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/api/Device/Login", apiURL];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:conURL]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:(@"content-type")];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:(@"accept")];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];  // This jsonData is populated elsewhere from a dictionary with [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:sectionsDict options:0 error:nil];

NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *authenticated = @"No";

if (error == nil) {

    if (response) {

        NSHTTPURLResponse *newResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
        NSLog(@"Authenticate - login - Response code - %li", (long)newResp.statusCode);

        if (data.length > 0 && error == nil) {

            NSLog(@"Authenticate - login - Data length - %li", (long)data.length);
            authenticated = @"Yes";

        } else {

            NSLog(@"Authenticate - login - Data length - %li", (long)data.length);
            NSLog(@"Authenticate - login - Error - %@", error);

        }

    } else {

        NSLog(@"Authenticate - login - No response - %@", response);

    }

} else {

    NSLog(@"Authenticate - login - login error - %li", (long)error.code);  // app currently gets here

    if (error.code != -1012) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"There was a problem!"
                                                                             message:@"The app is unable to login, the request timed out.  Please make sure there is an Internet connection and try again."
                                                                             delegate:self
                                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert setTag:2];
            [alert show];

    } else {

        NSLog(@"Authenticate - login - login error code - %li ", (long)error.code);  // app currently gets here

    }

}
```

I have tried both HTTP and HTTPS and this makes no difference.  What am I doing wrong?  What can I do to send successfuly POST request containing JSON in the body?

**UPDATE**

I have created a really simple test method that sends a POST request and this works fine.  I feel the problem is something to do with wrapping up the JSON I need to send and how the server receives it.

Working test:

```
NSString *string= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.mysite.com/api/Test/LoginSimplePost?username=%@&password=%@&portalid=%i",username,password,portalid];
NSLog(@"%@",string);
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSLog(@"responseData: %@", responseData);
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"responseData: %@", str);
```

Comment: You don't specify the length of you `jsonData` in `request`? Is your `jsonData` valid? How did you construct it? Note, that using `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error` is deprecated, and block the current thread (and if it's the main one, block UI). You should use NSURLSession.

Comment: @Larme I have just made an edit containing an explanation about the jsonData.  As this method is called I set a small graphical spinner and an alert box and block the UI while the app sends this login information to the API.  I don't need THIS call to be async.

Comment: Try to add `[request setValue:[jsonData length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];`, and also, there are parenthesis around `@"content-type"` and `@"accept"` (strange), and don't they have usually an uppercase ?

Comment: I have previously used them all as lower case with parenthesis - Xcode doesn't seem to like them without (in the working GET request it is like this too) but can certainly change this to test.

Comment: Can you show me your JSON data creation so we can get idea may be something suspect there ?

Comment: [request setValue:[jsonData length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]; gives an error and a warning in Xcode: "incompatible pointer conversion"... and "Implicit conversion of NSUInteger to NSString..."

Comment: @CodeChanger I have now added the rest of that method including the JSON creation section.

Comment: Sorry, missing conversion: `setValue:@([jsonData length])`, or use `setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",[jsonData length]]`

Comment: @Larme The app compiles and runs but I still get the same error.  Could this be an issue with how the JSON is serialized/sent?  As the exact same data works outside of the app.

Comment: is there any kind of app_secret that has been authenticated by server ?? may be by this its not allowing to access resources over server.

Comment: This is the first part of the 'user journey'.  The passing of the login info (along with basic device info) is open to anyone ([AllowAnonymous]).  Further interactions ARE handled by a token which is handed back AFTER successful login.

Comment: So may be you need to pass all detail in single dictionary or ask your web developer that what kind of request you want over there ?

Answer (score 0):

Below works for me may be that will help to you.

```
  - (void)UpdateUser:(NSDictionary *)userdetails {
      NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"SOME URL"];
      NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
      request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
      [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
      [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
      NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:userdetails options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil]; //don't set error to nil, handle the error
      [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
      NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
      [connection start];
    }
```

OR other case

This is **kCFURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication** error, -10xx errors are of the CFNetworkErrors enum. Name of this constant is pretty selfexplanatory. Server cancelled authentication for some reason

Comment: I kind of unserstand these errors are effectively the API not liking what is being sent but my error in this case is not kCFURLErrorUserCancelledAuthentication but instead kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork.  The headers and body which I send up using the app can be sent via Postman without issue.  I think the problem is the app is doing something with the data first.  Possibly encoding the JSON incorrectly?  UTF8 vs ASCII etc?